# Front derailleur never alligned

Tags: derailleur, shimano

So I'm working with the park tool tutorial but I've done it a couple of times in the past.
When adjusting my Shimano Deore Front derailleur (height and rotation) it lines up great but when I tighten the mounting bolt the whole thing **"banks"** inwards and so the cage bottom rises and touches the chain.

1. How to i set the height and tighten the mechanism with affecting the other rotation "axis" of the derailleur?
2. are there always combination of cogs (front and back) that will cause the chain to run against the cage?.

now some photos. it is very hard to create a stable reference angle with the phone and without a tripod but you will get the idea.
This is the chain on the **first (small) chainring** when the bolt is tighten:
[image: This is the chain on the **first (small) chainring** when the bolt is tighten]

And this is the chain still on the first (small) chainring but now the bolt is almost fully loose, so in fact, nothing changed with the actual position of the mount:
[image: And this is the chain still on the first (small) chainring but now the bolt is almost fully loose]

(please ignore the mud.... that's later on the list)
[image]

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: Technical issues with editing and uploading. All done with posting now eventually...

Comment: Start with it rotated the other direction so when you tighten it comes into proper alignment.

Comment: Yeah, it's not at all unusual to need to "misadjust" something before tightening, so that it lines up correctly when tight.  It's just a bit of trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one thing I would suggest trying to fix this problem while your chain is on your largest (highest) gear. Not only will you not have to worry about the cage hitting or being too close to your cranks, but usually I find that by making it fit with my chain on that highest gear, the other gears pretty much sort themselves out.

For securing the dérailleur to your frame, I typically aim for 2-4 cm above my largest chainring. After fixing the height, adjust your limiting screws on the dérailleur so that the cage is about 2 cm from the outside of your largest chainring and again about 2 cm from the inside of your smallest chainring (the first gear, smallest gear.)

Now, unfortunately (and especially if you're running a Shimano group set, there will most likely still be some noise from the chain rubbing against the dérailleur cage. This is something that most riders just have to deal with. I personally try and keep the noise to a minimum by making sure my chain is clean and lubed well so that it glides through the cage easier and quieter.

Good luck fixing your problem!

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Tighten the bolt and remember which direction and/or rotation the front derailleur is affected.
2. Readjust so that when tightened, the front derailleur is at optimum desired position, i.e. 2-3 mm above the 3rd chainring when at closest position to 3rd chainring, and parallel to the chainring.

There are of course combinations of front and rear gear that causes the chain-rub. The general rules are:

1. Low gear: Rear 1/2/3 - Front 1
2. Mid gear: Rear 3/4/5/6 - Front 2
3. High gear: rear 6/7/8/9/(10/11) - Front 3

From the look of your pictures, the derailleur is quiet high up when you tighten the bolt. Put it down a bit, but make sure it give clearance to shift your chain front 2 to 3 in front chainring.

Answer (score 0):

Isn’t your front derailler simply mounted way too high? As a rule of thumb when shifted to the big chainring it should be ~2mm above the big chainring and parallel to it.